# Iterative loop to query the most occurring field

Tags: database, linq, iteration

```
How do I implement iterative method to query the most occuring field from a class?
//Customers Class
public class Customers
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

the loop should return a certain age as most occurring age.

Comment: **Must** it be iterative? If not, look at [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971).

Comment: Yeah, it has to be an iterative loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a *grouping* - something like this:

```
List<Customer>  customers = new List<Customer>();
customers.Add(new Customer() { Age = 42});
//...

var biggestAgeGroup = customers.GroupBy(x=> x.Age)
                               .OrderByDescending(g=> g.Count())
                               .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Most occuring age:" + biggestAgeGroup.Key);
```

(Also took the liberty renaming your class to `Customer` - plural is for collections)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am looking for an iterative loop.

Comment: @Zherkov Why an iterative loop, when LINQ is much simpler. It does avoid a lot of errors that might occur when using iterative loops.

Answer (score 0):

I will start by saying that I like @BrokenGlass' answer much better, and `GroupBy` is definitely what I would use, but if you really *must* use an iterative loop then the following solution (updated from @BrokenGlass') updates should work:

```
List<Customer>  customers = new List<Customer>();
customers.Add(new Customer() { Age = 42});
//...

var ageCounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
int? mostCommonAge;
int mostCommonAgeCount;

for (var i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++) 
{
    var age = customers[i].Age;
    var ageCount = 1;

    if (!ageCounts.ContainsKey(age))
    {
        ageCount += ageCounts[age]; 
    }

    ageCounts[age] = ageCount;

    //can change logic if accounting for ties
    if (mostCommonAgeCount < ageCount) 
    {
        mostCommonAgeCount = ageCount; 
        mostCommonAge = age;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Most occuring age:" + mostCommonAge);
```

You can also do the same thing with a `Select` linq query, or a `List.ForEach` call. I don't add these because I didn't think they were what you were looking for.